# Mongo query not returning a result

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do my first mongoDB query on the following JSON document which I added to database using mongoimport.

```
     {
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionEntry": {
        "id": 1,
        "info": {
          "seasonNumber": 1,
          "episodeNumber": 1,
          "episodeName": "Days Gone Bye"
        },
        "questionItem": {
          "theQuestion": "q1",
          "attachedElement": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": ""
          }
        },
        "options": [
          {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "o1"
          },
          {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "o1"
          }
        ],
        "answer": {
          "questionId": 1,
          "answer": 1
        },
        "metaTags": [
          "Season 1",
          "Episode 1",
          "Rick Grimmes"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "questionEntry": {
        "id": 1,
        "info": {
          "seasonNumber": 1,
          "episodeNumber": 1,
          "episodeName": "Days Gone Bye"
        },
        "questionItem": {
          "theQuestion": "q2",
          "attachedElement": {
            "type": 1,
            "value": ""
          }
        },
        "options": [
          {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "o2"
          },
          {
            "type": 1,
            "value": "o2"
          }
        ],
        "answer": {
          "questionId": 1,
          "answer": 1
        },
        "metaTags": [
          "Season 1",
          "Episode 1",
          "Rick Grimmes",
          "Glenn Rhee"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried `db.questions.find({"questions.questionEntry.id" : "1"})` & `db.questions.find({"questions.questionEntry.id" : "1"})`
plus several other versions to try and query the id field of questionEntry. Every time the command prompt just returns to a new command prompt line "nothing"!?

If I run `db.questions.find()` then it returns the collection shown above.

What have/am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `db.questions.find({"questions.questionEntry.id" : 1}})`?

Comment: @chridam yes tried that and got unexpected token so removed the additional } and it worked - many thanks (looks like I had the 1 in brackets.

Comment: @chridam, thanks for answer. The query return the whole document shown above. Even when I query with db.questions.find({"questions.questionEntry.questionItem.theQuestion" : "q1" }) this brings back both questionEntrys in the question array even though the second questionEntry element has theQuestion field of "q2"!. With many questions here this seems a bit of a waste. Could I limit the returned query to only bring the array element which contains the query memebr?

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` is a number, not a string.

So the following should work:

```
db.questions.find({"questions.questionEntry.id" : 1})
```

Comment: Thanks that worked - but its returning the whole document back ( brings back both questionEntrys in the question array even though the second questionEntry element has theQuestion field of "q2"!). Is there a way to just return the array element that contains the queried item?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use `aggregate` and `$unwind` to do this kind of thing - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461690/how-to-project-only-matching-fields-of-nested-array-in-mongo-shell-query), or it might be better to change your schema e.g. by storing `questionEntry`s at the top level of your collection, rather than wrapping them inside an array and an outer document.